# Setting value of CheckBoxFor

Tags: c#, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to set the checkbox value (true/false) to a field. I can get the value, but cannot set it.

Within my Model I have:

```
public bool ReceiveNewsletter { get; set; }
```

In my View I have:

```
model Project.Models.Parent
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "ParentRegister", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "parent_register" }))
{
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => u.ReceiveNewsletter, new { @class = "checkbox", type = "checkbox" })
}
```

In my Controller I have:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Register(Models.Parent register)
 {
    return Content(register.SelectedIndex.ToString());
 }
```

When I load the application, the checkbox is unchecked because `ReceiveNewsletter` is `false` however, when I check the checkbox and click submit, it doesn't set the value to `true`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So are you saying when you check the checkbox and submit the form, you are not getting the true value in your HttpPost action method ?

Comment: @Shyju I don't have a HttpPost action method, surely upon submitting the form, the checkboxes value should be added to the field `ReceieveNewsletter` ?

Comment: so which action method is taking care of your submitted form ? Can you share the releavant action method code ?

Comment: @Shyju I have updated the question with more code. I have a `Html.TextBoxFor` which is binded to a `FirstName` field within the same model, when the constructor is called as the form is submitted it stores the correct value, I don't understand using the same method why it isn't working here with the checkbox

Comment: In your updated code, you have an HttpPost action method to handle your form post!. Earlier you said you did not have ! Did you inspect the `ReceiveNewsLetter` property on the posted model object ? Your code looks fine.

Comment: @Shyju Yes, it contains value of false still

Comment: Your code looks fine to me !

Comment: There is no point adding `type = "checkbox"` (the `CheckBoxFor()` method already does that. The code you have shown will work correctly (the value of `register.ReceiveNewsletter` will be `true` if the checkbox is checked). If its not, then the problem is with code that your have not shown us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your get action method looks like(I'm assumed it is already correct), but you are passing in the type of Parent that is named register to your HttpPost action method. Your HttpPost action method should look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(Models.Parent register)
{
    return Content(register.ReceivesNewsLetter.ToString());
}
```

I think it would also be helpful if you showed us your get action method so we can make sure you get the answer you are looking for. I was going to leave a comment under your question, but I don't have enough points to do that.